# How to properly solve the producer consumer in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I'm trying to solve the producer consumer problem in C++11.
I have an object which holds resources, and multiple threads can
add or consume those resources. My problem is when I try to implement
a "consume when available" method on that object.
Please assume that insert/remove operations are of trivial complexity.

A little explanation of the logic in code.

```
struct ResourceManager{
  std::mutex mux;
  std::unique_lock lock{mux};
  std::condition_variable bell;

  void addResource(/*some Resource*/){
    lock.lock();
    //add resource
    lock.unlock();
    bell.notify_one(); //notifies waiting consumer threads to consume
  }

  T getResource(){
    while(true){
      lock.lock();
      if(/*resource is available*/){
        //remove resource from the object
        lock.unlock();
        return resource;
      }else{
        //new unique lock mutex object wmux creation
        lock.unlock(); //problem line
        bell.wait(wmux); //waits until addResource rings the bell
        continue;
      }
    }
  }

};
```

Suppose the following scenario:
-Two threads, T1, T2, call addResource, getResource almost simultaneously.

-T2 locks the mutex, and finds out there are no more resources available,
  so it has to block until a new resource is available.
  So it unlocks the mutex and sets up the bell waiting.

-T1 runs match faster. When the mutex is unlocked, 
it immediately adds the resource, and before T2 sets up the waiting bell,
T1 has already rang the bell, which notifies no one.

-T2 indefinitely waits for the bell to ring, but no further resources are added.

I'm making the assumption that a thread locking a mutex, may be the only one
to unlock it. So if I tried calling bell.wait before unlocking the mutex,
the mutex could never be unlocked.

I'd like to use no time-waiting or multiple times checking solution if possible.
So which way could I solve this problem in C++11?

Comment: May be not related to your problem, but please use lock guards like `std::unique_lock` for locking/unlocking mutexes.

Comment: lock is a unique_lock

Comment: What is `wmux`? You should have `lock` locked, and perform `bell.wait(lock)`, to avoid a race condition.

Comment: @FrustratedSoul Oh, sorry. But that's not how to use it. Usually you don't have a member variable, but a local variable that just unlocks the mutex when leaving it's scope.

Comment: @FrustratedSoul:  I've removed my solution and invite you to check proper usage of unique_lock and condition_variable at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait  the example is pretty much exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
    lock.unlock(); //problem line
    bell.wait(wmux); //waits until addResource rings the bell
```

Yes, this is the problem line, indeed.

To correctly use a condition variable as designed, you do ***not*** unlock a mutex before `wait()`ing on its related condition variable.  `wait()`ing on a condition variable atomically unlocks it for the duration of the wait, and reacquires the mutex once the thread has been `notify()`-ed. Both the unlock-and-wait, and wake-up-after-being-notified-and-lock, are atomic operations.

All`notify()`s  should be issued while the mutex is locked. All `wait()` are also done while the mutex is fully locked. Given that `notify()`, as I mentioned, is atomic, this results in all mutex-related operations being atomic and fully sequenced, including managing the resources protected by the mutex, and thread notification via condition variables, which is now protected by a mutex as well.

There are design patterns that can be implemented that notify condition variables without using mutex protection. But they're much harder to implement correctly and still achieve thread-safe semantics. Having all condition variable operations also protected by the mutex, in addition to everything else that the mutex protects, is much simpler to implement.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
So, if I understood correctly, in addResource, bell.notify_one() should be called before the mutex is unlocked.
In addition, in getResource,I should delete lock.unlock(), and use bell.wait(lock) instead of bell.wait(wmux);
Have I got it right?

Comment: That sounds correct; of course this depends on the actual implementation details, as you've only summarized your code in your question. Note [the requirement for wait()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait): "lock - an object of type std::unique_lock<std::mutex>, which ***must be locked by the current thread***".

Answer (score 1):

`std::condition_variable::wait` needs to be passed a locked `std::unique_lock` on your mutex.  `wait` will unlock the mutex as part of its operation, and will re-lock it before it returns.

The normal way to use lock guards like `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock` is to construct them locally and let their constructor lock your mutex and their destructor unlock it.

Also, you can avoid the external `while` loop in your original code by providing a predicate to `std::condition_variable::wait`.

```
struct ResourceManager {
  std::mutex mux;
  std::condition_variable bell;

  void addResource(T resource)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mux};
    // Add the resource
    bell.notify_one();
  }

  T getResource()
  {
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mux};
     bell.wait(lock, [this](){ return resourceIsAvailable(); });
     return // the ressource
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, your answer nicely describes what another person has already answered here before. A pity he deleted his post :S